# Sessions lost after form submitting

Tags: php, forms, submit

i code a form with four steps in PHP. I submit each step with POST method.

My steps looks like the first:

```
    if(trim($_GET['p']) == 1){
        $_SESSION['rate_step'] = $_GET['p'];
        $_SESSION['data_change'] = @$_POST['change'];

        if(@$_POST['change'] != ''){
            $_SESSION['rate_disabled'] = '';
        }

        if(@$_POST['new_rate'] != ''){
            $_SESSION['rate_disabled'] = '';
            if($_SESSION['rate_lastinsertid'] != ''){
                $_SESSION['rate_lastinsertid'] = '';
            };
        }

        $extra_vis = 'display:none';
        $content = show_template('agent_rates_s1', array(   
                                                    'step' => $_SESSION['rate_step'],
                                                    'monat' => $monat,
                                                    'jahr' => $jahr,
                                                    'jahr_zukunft' => $jahrfut,
                                                    'zielland' => $zielland,
                                                    'herkunfstland' => $herkunfstland,
                                                    'service' => $_SESSION['rate_service'],
                                                    'month_service' => $_SESSION['rate_month'],
                                                    'year_service' => $_SESSION['rate_year'],
                                                    'origin_country' => $_SESSION['rate_origin_country'],
                                                    'destination_country' => $_SESSION['rate_destination_country'],
                                                    'city' => $_SESSION['rate_city'],
                                                    'street' => $_SESSION['rate_street'],
                                                    'postcode' => $_SESSION['rate_postcode'],
                                                    'floor' => $_SESSION['rate_floor'],
                                                    'disabled' => $_SESSION['rate_disabled'],
                                                    'extra_vis' => $extra_vis,

        ));
    }
```

When I click on another menu item in the navigation and get than back to my form or the first step fields are empty. Every Session is empty. Why ?

Is the problem that I use $_GET['p'] == 1 and so on?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you start the session?

Comment: @Swellar yes I clear the sessions with session_start();

Comment: Based on your indentation, is the first `if` statement supposed to be closed on line 4?

Comment: @PeterMellett no because I close the statement after my $content variable to show $content.

Comment: Ah I see, please could you fix your formatting so the code is more clear?

Comment: you check $_GET['p']  and other two values with post method that's why $_POST become empty. You can use either GET or POST or you can use $_REQUEST to handle both types GET & POST If you not sure about method type.

Comment: @Sachin so I use POST to check which form is submitted and show the content?

Comment: Okay so you need to check $_POST['p'] instead of $_GET['p'] or you can replace $_GET and $_POST with $_REQUEST.